# SQLAlchemy IntegrityError violated constraint name

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have a lot of different constraints on columns of the database tables. Data that inserted into the database usually contain arrays of numbers (on these numbers constraints were set), for example (part of DDL):

```sql
CREATE TABLE "Object" (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES "Generic" (id)  // Inheritance
);

CREATE TABLE "ObjectData" (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    x FLOAT NOT NULL, 
    y FLOAT NOT NULL, 
    d FLOAT NOT NULL, 
    a FLOAT NOT NULL, 
    e FLOAT NOT NULL, 
    object_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    CONSTRAINT "duplicate x, y values" UNIQUE (x, y, object_id), 
    CONSTRAINT "x must be >= -1.0" CHECK (x >= 0.0), 
    CONSTRAINT "x must be <= 1.0" CHECK (x <= 1.0), 
    CONSTRAINT "y must be >= -1.0" CHECK (y >= -1.0), 
    CONSTRAINT "y must be <= 1.0" CHECK (y <= 1.0), 
    CONSTRAINT "d must be >= -1.0" CHECK (d >= 0.0), 
    CONSTRAINT "d must be <= 1.0" CHECK (d <= 1.0), 
    CONSTRAINT "a must be >= -270.0" CHECK (a >= -270.0), 
    CONSTRAINT "a must be <= 270.0" CHECK (a <= 270.0), 
    CONSTRAINT "e must be >= -1.0" CHECK (e >= -1.0), 
    CONSTRAINT "e must be <= 1.0" CHECK (e <= 1.0), 
    FOREIGN KEY(object_id) REFERENCES "Object" (id)
);
```

Inserting data looks like the follows (part of input text file that parsed to insert into DB):

```sql
DATA:
-1.0  -1.0  1.0  242.0  0.0
-1.0  -2.0  1.0  124.0  0.0
-1.0  -1.0  1.0  109.0  0.0
...........................
-1.0  -1.0  1.0  242.0  0.0
-1.0  -2.0  1.0  124.0  0.0
-1.0  -1.0  1.0  109.0  0.0
```

So if any of these values will violate one of constraint and no message will show then it extremely hard to determine which of values are bad. For this purposes descriptive names of constraints were given. Work with **SQLite3** database carry out by means of **SQLAlchemy ORM** and when sqlalchemy.exc.IntegretyError occures this library completly cut off name of violated constraint.

Googling result in presence of constraint name in IntegrityError exception in SQLite3  have been started from [version 3.3.2][1]. That shows short test in Python REPL:

```py
>>> import sqlite3
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect('test/test.db')
>>> c = conn.cursor()
>>> c.execute("""INSERT INTO "ObjectData" (x, y, d, a, e, object_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)""", (-2.0, -1.0, 1.0, 242.0, 0.0, 1))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
IntegrityError: CHECK constraint failed: x must be >= -1.0
```

But when I try to insert data using SQLAlchemy I get only message that can't describe nothing what happened wrong. Here the result of dir(error):

```py
detail = []
params = (-2.0, -1.0, 1.0, 242.0, 0.0, 1)
statement = INSERT INTO "ObjectData" (x, y, d, a, e, object_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
instance = <bound method type.instance of <class 'sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError'>>
args = ('(IntegrityError) constraint failed',)
orig = constraint failed
orig.message = constraint failed
```

So the question is there any way to force SQLAlchemy return violated constraint name because it greatly simplified code and allow to show user informative messages about errors? Or may be other way exists?

Comment: Generally, I enforce constraints at the ORM layer, since it's easier to handle (and easier to change). Is that an option for you?

Otherwise, it looks like you can use SQLAlchemy reflection to map the table and table constraints and possibly get better results. http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/constraints.html#check-constraint

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem to enforce constraints at the ORM layer is that SQLite3 DB is local file which can be changed not just only my soft. Because all objects is not loaded from DB at the startup then it will be looks very strange for user when program will display warning box at one of tabs and furthermore currently I can't suggest obvious way to handle described case. It seems more reliable to check constraint at DB. So could you please provide more info about second options (I don't quite understand how to implement it).

Comment: I saw you got it working, which I'm glad about. Reflection in SQLAlchemy is pretty complicated, but basically you can point it at a table and automatically extract all the metadata about it (tables, columns, and constraints), and then use that to run queries. It's not for the faint of heart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found what was wrong with SQLAlchemy library usage. When I ran software in debug mode and break when IntegrityError exception raised (break point was set in DBAPIError.instance method of SQLAlchemy library) then I've realised that original error type is class 'pysqlite2._sqlite.Error' rather than sqlite3. It appeared that in site-package library pysqlite2 has been installed in my Python environment but that is not the same sqlite3. I tried to use simple workaround: delete pysqlite2 directory from the site-package. After that original exception type become class 'sqlite3.Error' and orig.message in exception contain exactly what I expect. So it obvious that SQLAlchemy use pysqlite2 library by default rather than built-in sqlite3 library.